# Setting a .sde connection file as a default value in an ArcPy toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, python-toolbox

I am building a tool to run some routine data maintenance on an Enterprise geodatabase with Python. I would like to set the default value for one of the parameters to database connection file on disk. The problem is whenever, I set the default value to the file path of the .sde file, I get a vague ArcGIS ERROR 000820: The parameters need repair. Alternatively, if I don't set a default value in the toolbox, and select the exact same .sde file through the UI, the tool runs as expected. Here is a snippet of the code I am using (I've replaced CreateDatabaseConnection parameters, with stand-ins in this example):

```
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Input SDE Connection",
        name = "in_conn_file",
        datatype= "DEWorkspace",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")
    
    SDE_Connection = arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(out_path, out_name, database_platform, instance, account_authentication, username, password, database = database)
    param0.value =  SDE_Connection
    
    param0.filter.list = ["Remote Database"]
```

Comment: I suspect this is another [Result object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm) issue you are having. What happens if you use `param0.value =  SDE_Connection[0]`

Comment: I still get the same error message when I use `param0.value = SDE_Connection[0]`. I've also tried using the filepath of the .sde file as the default value with the same result.